# How to understand property (c) of the definition of probability?

Tags: probability

I am reading *Probability and Statistical Inference* by Robert V. Hogg et al. The followins is the property (c) of the definition of probability:

> (c) if $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ are events and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset, i \neq j$, then
> $$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots A_k) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + \dots + P(A_k)$$
> for each positive integer $k$, and
> $$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \dots) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + P(A_3) + \dots$$
> for an infinite, but countable, number of events.

Is it necessary to state the probability equation for (case 1) $k$, and (case 2) an infinite but countable number, respectively? And why?

Comment: The countable additivity does not generally follow from finite additivity. It needs to be postulated separately. In case 2 also, the events must be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: To state the finite additivity separately is redundant, though.